# How to get rid of .0 on end of whole float number

Tags: java

I am trying to get rid of the .0 left behind a float number when I add whole numbers together. ex. if i do 10+10 it will print out 20.0 but i want it to print out 20 unless there is a decimal in the number.
P.S ive been looking all over on this site and cant find the anser to my question so why did someone make this a duplicate makes no sense.

```
float numOne = Float.parseFloat(numberOne.getText());
    float numTwo = Float.parseFloat(numberTwo.getText());
    float anser = numOne+numTwo;
    String AR = String.valueOf(anser);
        anserLabel.setText(AR);
```

Comment: Cast value to an int?

Comment: why would I cast it to an int...... I need it to be float cause there will be decimals in the numbers, its just that if the 2 numbers put together are whole dumbers i dont want the useless .0 after the whole number